# Apache POI write time greater than 24

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I want to write a excel file. In this file there are some column where I put the time values like "11:21". In the last row of this column, I want to add these time values and show the total like"123:23". For this I am using the following code:

```
HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
                    cellStyle.setDataFormat(HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat("h:mm"));
                    c.setCellValue(DateUtil.convertTime("49:12"));
                    c.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
```

But It is giving me the following error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad time format '49:12' expected 'HH:MM' or 'HH:MM:SS' - hour value (49) is outside the allowable range(0..23)

Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

This approach worked for me:
1. Set a custom data format [h]:mm
2. Get a java.util.Date object for your time using a SimpleDateFormat
3. Excel's epoch is 1900, so set the year in your Date object to 1900 using Calendar
4. Set cell value as your Date object after deducting 1 day

```
CreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();

CellStyle hhmmStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
hhmmStyle.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("[h]:mm"));

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

xlsCell.setCellStyle(hhmmStyle);

Date time = sdf.parse("49:00");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(time);
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1900);

xlsCell.setCellValue(DateUtil.getExcelDate(cal.getTime())-1.0);
```

Comment: Thanks a ton friend, worked like a charm. Just curious on why that deduction of 1.0 ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `SimpleDateFormat`,

```
    SimpleDateFormat _24HourFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    SimpleDateFormat _12HourFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
```

For example

```
SimpleDateFormat _24HourFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
Date date = _24HourFormat.parse("49:12");
cell.setCellValue(date);
```

Comment: Getting values like "613671h 40m"

Answer (score -1):

You could add an apostrophe at the first position of your data in order to set the value as `String`, no need to set the value as a `Date`.

```
c.setCellValue("'49:12");
```

Comment: But I want to use this total and one more column total to add as a time using the excel sum function. Like 40:11 + 30:10=70:21.

Comment: I don't have the Apache POI at hand at the moment, maybe you could try setting the value w/o using a data format.